Note taking apps for Android that require least steps to write a note
I need a simple note keeping app

I don't need multiple documents or formatting pr history or any advance feature

It needs to have android app and web app with auto sync between them

Optional: audio to text notes feature

It should have least number of steps required to write a note. Because I write them many times a day and it's annoying to go through multiple actions if I am in hurry



Checkout logseq and it's android app - sync can be done via syncthing or by paying for their service.
